# Typescript call function hooks dynamically with different generic parameter types

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-conversion, typeerror

```
export {}

interface Hooks {
  onSuccess: (x: number) => void
  onError: (x: string) => void
}

const hooks: Partial<Hooks> = {
  onSuccess: (x) => console.log(x),
  onError: (x) => console.log(x),
}

function callHook<K extends keyof Hooks>(key: K, param: Parameters<Hooks[K]>[0]) {
  hooks[key]?.(param) // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}

function submit() {
  // Call Hook onSuccess
  callHook('onSuccess', 123)

  // Call Hook onError
  callHook('onError', 'Forbidden')
}

submit()
```

I'm getting this error here: `hooks[key]?.(param)`

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Any solution for the above code?

Comment: [Parameters built-in type](https://tsplay.dev/mx83bm)

Comment: @caTS is there any other solution without //@ts-ignore

because it's not look like a proper typescript solution.

Comment: @jcalz would you like to answer this question.